# Handling Backbone routing without hashtag

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

So what I'm attempting to do is trigger and load a view when someone goes to my site with a URL that is not found in my routing. I'm doing this so that visitors can view a users profile by visiting domain.com/username

Since the username is dynamic I cannot define routing, how would I accomplish the triggering that I need ?

Comment: I think you have to do a server-side rewrite to handle this scenario.  The server should treat `domain.com/username` as simply `domain.com` (optionally you might want to verify on the server, first, that the username actually exists).

Comment: Why don't you want to use hash?  They could navigate to domain.com/#username instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle that in the router:

```
 var myRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            '/:username': findUsername,
            '*path': notFound
        }
        findUsername: function(usernme) {
            //Find username
            //Username param comes from URL
        },
        notFound: function() {
            //Handle not found page
        }
    });
```

The one caveat is when your app loads, you need to start the backbone history with `{ pushState: true }`

```
new myRouter();
Backbone.history.start({ pushState: true });
```

Comment: You can't do this - Backbone routes on the URL fragment, not on the URL itself so none of this routing will fire

Comment: You are right. I updated the code to remove the domain from the URL. Thanks!

Comment: Your code will still do the same thing. You can pass the router _any_ pattern to match, and it will only match against the URL fragment _not_ the pathname

Comment: It will match to the pathname depending if you pass the following option to the router: Backbone.history.start({pushState: true}).

Comment: I edited the answer to include that bit of information.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with Backbone as it's router only routes on the URL fragment (hash), not the URL itself. Using the HTML5 History API won't work either as this is a direct navigation to a URL.

Your only option here is to do your routing on the server and serve a page with all your Backbone client logic in it.

You could potentially hack about with `window.location.pathname` but this is suboptimal and will likely result in more tears than usual.